# How to generate noise with a chosen spatial distribution with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, matplotlib, noise

I want to add noise to an image in a way similar to this :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

myImage = plt.imread('Pikachu.png')
noise = np.random.normal(0, 0.1, (myImage.shape[0], myImage.shape[1]))

noisyImage = myImage + noise
```

However, I would need the noise to be more intense in the center of the image, and less intense as we get farther from the center.

Ideally, I could regulate the spatial distribution parameter of the noise so that my `noise` variable contains :

- Initialization : Intense and uniform noise on all the image
- Early stages : Intense noise in the center, less noise on the borders
- Mid-stages : Noise in the center, no more noise on the border
- Late stages : No more noise on all the image (all zeros)

Does anyone know a way to do it? Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Create a Gaussian matrix with the same shape as your image and multiply it element-wise with the noise matrix

Comment: **Init:** have very large spread/std dev, multiply by large number
**early(mid):** Low spread/std dev, multiply by large(small) number
**late:** multiply noise by zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something you could use as a starting point:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def gauss2D(shape,sx=1,sy=1):
    """
    unnormalized 2D gauss centered on mean value, 
    given shape and standard dev (sx and sy).
    """
    mx = shape[0]/2
    my = shape[1]/2

    return np.exp( -0.5*(
        ((np.arange(shape[0])[:,None]-mx)/sx)**2+
        ((np.arange(shape[0])[None,:]-my)/sy)**2
        ))#/(2*np.pi*sx*sy)

width,height = 64,64
my_img = np.zeros((width,height,3))+0.9
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()
N=5
for i in range(N):
    my_img[:,:,:]=0.5 #gray bg image
    w = N*100/(4**(2*i))
    A = (1-.1*(i+1))
    noise =A*np.random.normal(0,w,(width,height))*gauss2D((width,height),10,10)
    plt.imshow(my_img+noise[:,:,None]) #noise affects rgb equally
    plt.title(i)
    plt.show()
```

with output:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Here the noise was sampled from a gaussian distribution, but a uniform distribution should work fine.

The important part is to *weight the noise* by a gaussian to get the effect you desire.

You might want to tweak `A`(amplitude), and `w`(spread) to fit your needs(it could just be two lists). You want high amplitude and spread early, then first decrease spread possibly increasing the amplitude, then decreasing the amplitude to zero.